# How to create a website after creating code in Adobe brackets?

Tags: html, adobe, adobe-brackets

I'm new to coding, quite obviously. I created a web design using HTML in Adobe brackets. How do I create my own website from here? Like getting a domain or host. Not sure if those are even the right words to use

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of web development! Congrats on making your first HTML site.

I am not sure how much you know about the topic, so I will try to explain the basics of getting a site "online".

1. Websites essentially allow you to access other people's HTML documents in a file directory. You have probably noticed some URLs in the form "www.example.com/file.html". This means that to get your site online, you will need a computer to "host" your HTML files from. Since you probably don't want to leave your computer on 24/7, you will need to use a web hosting service. There are loads of web hosting companies that offer similar services, but they all have the same goal essentially - providing the means for people to remotely access your files. My hosting service of choice is [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com) because they offer a decent price on a small web server. Through your web server (which is essentially a computer running Linux in a warehouse somewhere), you can install web server software (like Apache) which will allow you place your html files into a special directory which will can be accessed from a web browser (something like /var/www/html). Once your files are uploaded to your server, you can access your website through your server's IP address (some esoteric number in the form of http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).
2. Of course, you don't access websites through an IP address (at least most humans don't). This is where a "domain name" comes in. The web provides a nifty feature (DNS) which allows you to map a domain name to an IP address. So you can go to your favorite domain purchasing website (something like [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com), which you have probably heard of) and purchase an open domain name of choice. Once you purchase the domain (something like DragonFire09.com), you can map this domain name to your web server's IP address.

These are the two main steps to getting a site online! I hope this provides some insight. Note that getting a website online costs money because you need to pay for a hosting service and a domain, however its a great experience because along the way you will get your hands dirty with Linux and other parts of the web stack.

Of course, you can always create files locally and test them through your own web browser free of charge.

Good luck!